# Restrict access to a table in SQL Lab in Superset

Tags: apache-superset

I have database with many tables. Users have full access to this database and tables to create various charts and dashboards. They use SQL Lab extensively to write custom queries.

However I added a sensitive data in a separate table that needs to be accessed only by few set of users. How can I achieve?

I tried ROW-LEVEL-SECURITY feature.
However, this affects only to Virtual Tables created by Superset. I want to restrict during direct SQL Lab access also.

Possible Solution:

> Create ACL at database level and create a seperate connection in Superset.
> Cons - This requires a duplicate connection to same database twice.

Ideal solution:
To restrict SQL Lab access to specific tables at superset level. e.g Superset should check User roles and ACLs and decide upon a table can be queried or not.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe consider implement proper access control to your data with Ranger and from superset impersonate login user.

Answer (score 0):

In the roles, there are permissions to give access to a particular dataset.
Ex: `Datasource_access_on_yourDatasetName`

If you give access to Database, user can access the database, and for that, you give access to a particular dataset. Then the user can be able to have access to that dataset only and query from that dataset.